# Passing a specific shape as a function argument

Tags: variables, powerpoint, argument-passing, shapes

Using Powerpoint 2010 and MS Visual Basic for applications:

I'm trying to pass a specific shape as an argument... Tried different syntax or ways of doing it but no luck, it seems to block at using the oShape Variable between the functions.

Function ClickBtn1() sets the oShape variable to the name of the shape to be modified and the calls the modifying function Incre().

Incre() set a numerical value to 12, updates the text range from the shape to it and then changes the forecolor to 10, 10, 10 and it then redraws the slide...

What I have goes like this:

```
Dim oShape As Shape
Dim x As Long

Sub ClickBtn1()
MsgBox "Inside ClickBtn1"
oShape = ActivePresentation.Slides(7).Shapes("ParaIcon")
Incre
End Sub

Sub Incre()
MsgBox "inside Incre"
x = 12
oShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = x
oShape.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(10, 10, 10)
SlideShowWindows(7).View.GotoSlide (SlideShowWindows(7).View.Slide.SlideIndex)
End Sub
```

I have an arrow shape with action set to "run macro ClickButton1" and a rectangle called "ParaIcon" on slide 7 of a Powerpoint document...

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do it like so instead; avoid global variables and use SET for assigning object references to variables.

```
Sub ClickBtn1()
    Dim oShape as Shape
    MsgBox "Inside ClickBtn1"
    SET oShape = ActivePresentation.Slides(7).Shapes("ParaIcon")
    Incre oShape    
End Sub

Sub Incre(oShape as Shape)
    Dim x as Long
    MsgBox "inside Incre"
    x = 12

    ' Convert numbers to string before assigning text
    oShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Cstr(x)

    oShape.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(10, 10, 10)
    SlideShowWindows(7).View.GotoSlide (SlideShowWindows(7).View.Slide.SlideIndex)    
End Sub
```